# How to change a radio button value from a textbox value

Tags: textbox, joomla, radio-button

i would love to have the textbox value as my radio button value. For example, if I type "1" in the textbox, then the radio button value would change to "1".I hope i could find answers here. By the way, i am using Joomla, and if there are javascripts, pls tell me where to paste it. thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i solved it :D
here it is.

$('#textbox').keyup(function(event){
     var value = $(this).val();
     $('#radio').val(value);
  });

you also need to change the value of your #radio to the id of your textbox e.g